# Extract session fails only on php 8

Tags: session, typeerror, extract

I have a site working fine with php 7.4 - no php warnings or errors. But when I switch it to php 8 it fails with this

```
    Uncaught TypeError: extract(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given
```

The command it fails on is

```
    extract($_SESSION, EXTR_OVERWRITE+EXTR_REFS);
```

If I call is_array($_SESSION) it says it isn't an array. But the session_start function is called before the above and it returns that the session was started.

Does anyone have an idea as to what the cause of this is? Or what to try?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs across this problem, it turned out to be the version of php 8 that was installed didn't have a value for output buffering. I set that and the site works properly now.